# Generating binary numbers with length n with same amount of 1's and 0's

Tags: bitmask

Question same as in the title. 
I've done two approaches. One is straightforward. 
Generate all bitmasks from

> 2^{n-1}

to

> 2^n

And for every bitmask check if there is same amount 1's and 0's, if yes, work on it.
And that's the problem, because i have to work on those bitmasks not only count them.

I came with second approach which runs on O(2^{n/2}) time, but seems like it's not generating all bitmasks and i don't know why.

Second approach is like that : 
generate all bitmasks from 0 to 2^{n/2} and to have valid bitmask( call it B ) i have to do something like this : B#~B

where ~ is negative.

So for example i have n=6, so i'm going to generate bitmasks with length of 3.

For example i have B=101, so ~B will be 010
and final bitmask would be 101010, as we see, we have same amount of 1's and 0's.

Is this method good or am i implementing something bad ? Maybe some another interesting approach exist?
Thanks

Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a recursive approach:

```
void printMasks(int n0, int n1, int mask) {
    if (!n0 && !n1) {
        cerr << mask << endl;
        return;
    }
    mask <<= 1;
    if (n0) {
        printMasks(n0-1, n1, mask);
    }
    if (n1) {
        printMasks(n0, n1-1, mask | 1);
    }
}
```

Call `printMasks` passing it the desired number of 0's and 1's. For example, if you need 3 ones and 3 zeros, call it like this:

```
printMasks(3, 3, 0);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for it, but it doesn't work so good, i mean...
for arguments 3,3,0
it generate not good bitmasks before number 35, after that it gives good numbers. I've checked it with my bruteforce

Comment: @Chris what do you mean? It works very well: for `printMasks(2, 2, 0)` I got 3, 5, 6, 9, 10, and 12 - i.e. `0011`, `0101`, `0110`, `1001`, `1010`, and `1100` - all possible combinations with 2 ones and 2 zeros. Could you give an example of a *not good* number that you get running 3,3,0?

Comment: For `printMasks(3,3,0)` i have numbers like 25 which is `11001` which as we see has 2 zeros and 3 ones. And other numbers like 21, 22.
But after that i have 35,37,38,41 and so on and those numbers works well. 
It would be great if you could help fix it :)

Comment: @Chris 25 is `011001`, so it is good. If you need a number with the initial `1`, it is a simple change: call `printMasks(3, 2, 1)` (I subtracted one from n1, because the initial `1` is already there in the `mask`).

Comment: Hey there, thanks a lot, that's working very fine and i guess would be much faster than generating all `2^n` bitmasks :) 
Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, given a binary number, to produce the next higher binary number which has the same number of 'ones', using a constant number of operations on words large enough to hold all the bits (assuming that division by a power of two counts as one operation).

Identify the positions of the least significant '1' (hint: what happens if you decrement the number) and the least significant '0' above that (hint: what happens if you add the "least significant 1" to the original number?)  You should change that least significant '0' to a '1', and set the proper number of least-significant bits to '1', and set the intervening bits to '0'.